# Why std::invoke_result_t gives other return type for a callable than a trait?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, invoke-result

Snippet:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct CallableTrait;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct CallableTrait<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    using ReturnType = R;
};

template <typename Callable>
using CallableTraitT = CallableTrait<decltype(std::function{std::declval<Callable>()})>;

const int foo(const int x)
{
    int r = x + 42;
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    using ReturnT1 = CallableTraitT<decltype(foo)>::ReturnType;
    using ReturnT2 = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(foo), decltype(42)>;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<ReturnT1, const int>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<ReturnT2, int>);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3qnajd)

Why does `std::invoke_result_t` strip off the `const` from the `foo` return type?

I would like to wrap a callable into another callable with the exact same return type, but apparently I cannot rely `std::invoke_result_t` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how the language works.

A function's return type can be nominally `const`-qualified (and that's what you're getting out of `CallableTrait`), but the actual result of invoking such a function (i.e. the expression containing the function call) has the `const` stripped off if it's a built-in type (for being useless), and that's the thing that `invoke_result` is telling you about.

> [`[expr.type/2]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#2): If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`”, where `T` is a *cv-unqualified* non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

Admittedly this is a bit of an oddity, but that's how it is.